# cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function

Tags: reactjs

I have this hook:

```
export const authenticationReducer = (
  state: { busy: boolean; isAuthenticated: boolean },
  action: AuthenticatedActions
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case AuthenticatedActionTypes.SetIsAuthenticated: {
      return { ...action.payload };
    }
    case AuthenticatedActionTypes.SetBusy: {
      return { ...state, busy: action.payload.busy };
    }
    default:
      throw new Error(`no case for ${action} in AuthenticationReducer`);
  }
};

export const useIsUserAuthenticated = () => {
  const [{ busy, isAuthenticated }, dispatch] = useReducer(
    authenticationReducer,
    initialState
  ) as any;

  useEffect(() => {
    let isSubscribed = true;
    (async () => {
      try {
        console.log({ isSubscribed });
        dispatch(setBusy(true));

        const currentSession = await fakeApi();
        const isAuthenticated = !!(currentSession && currentSession.isValid);

        isSubscribed && dispatch(setIsAuthenticated(isAuthenticated));
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        isSubscribed && dispatch(setIsAuthenticated(false));
      }
    })();

    return () => {
      isSubscribed = false;
    };
  }, [dispatch]);

  return { busy, isAuthenticated };
};
```

I have had to hack a `isSubscribed` local variable that I both check before dispatching

`isSubscribed && dispatch(setIsAuthenticated(isAuthenticated));`

And I have to return from the `useEffect` or else I get this error:

> cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function

The hook is used like this:

import React from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { useIsUserAuthenticated } from "./useIsUserAuthenticated";

```
export interface AuthenticationContainerProps {
  redirectTo: string;
}

export const AuthenticatedContainer: React.FC<AuthenticationContainerProps> = ({
  children,
  redirectTo
}) => {
  const { busy, isAuthenticated } = useIsUserAuthenticated();

  if (busy) {
    return <h1>Busyyyyyy</h1>;
  }

  return isAuthenticated ? <>{children}</> : <Redirect to={redirectTo} />;
};
```

I really don't like this hack but cannot think of a better way.

I have created a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/privateroute-wierdness-mq7l4) that illustrates the problem but it does not seem to happen in the codesandbox but does in the real application.

This seems awful, is there a better way?

Comment: Is that an error or warning? This will be resolved even when you return ()=>{}. I think since you are using async functions in effect react expects a cleanup function.

Comment: returning an empty function won’t cure this